# Extract kernel module binary from load_module arguments in Linux

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I’m researching how kernel modules work on Linux and trying to figure out how to extract the kernel module binary that is mapped during init_module syscall execution.
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/module/main.c#L2894

I see that init_module takes load_info structure as an argument however I can’t understand how the kernel module is mapped to it, it’s clearly that copy_module_from_user function is responsible for mapping the kernel module binary to load_info structure.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/module/main.c#L1825

However I’m stuck on extracting the binary from load_info.
Basically my question is how to read kernel module bytecode from load_module.

Comment: Have a look at insmod command source code where module is loaded from user space and then a system call to init_module is made [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kernel/kmod/kmod.git/tree/libkmod/libkmod-module.c#n939).

Comment: Have a look at this [excellent disection of a kernel module](https://terenceli.github.io/%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF/2018/06/02/linux-loadable-module). Good luck and good question!